# Установка цветовой схемы в vim

Tags: vim

Cоздал файл `~\.vimrc` и поместил в нем единственную строчку

> colorscheme xoria256

Скачал файл **xoria256.bin** вот [от сюда](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2140). Подскажите, куда его нужно поместить чтобы стиль применялся?

**Обновление**

Пробовал так

```
volk@sivadra:~$ # в домашний папки есть файл .vimrc
volk@sivadra:~$ cat ~/.vimrc
colorscheme xoria256
volk@sivadra:~$ # я создал папку .vim а в ней каталог colors
volk@sivadra:~$ cd ~/.vim/colors/
volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ # и туда поместил скаченный файл
volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ ls
xoria256.bin
volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ # но не смотря на это vim выдает ошибку при старте
volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ vim
```

> Обнаружена ошибка при обработке
> /home/volk/.vimrc: строка    1:
>
> E185: Невозможно найти цветовую схему
> 'xoria256'

Answer (score 1):

В ~/.vim/colors

**Обновление**

Попробуйте добавить в начало .vimrc следующие строки:

```
" Configure 256 colors for xterm mode
if &term =~ "xterm"
  let &t_Co=256
endif
```

Comment: я пробовал так

volk@sivadra:~$ # в домашний папки есть файл .vimrc

volk@sivadra:~$ cat ~/.vimrc

colorscheme xoria256

volk@sivadra:~$ # я создал папку .vim а в ней каталог colors

volk@sivadra:~$ cd ~/.vim/colors/

volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ # и туда поместил скаченный файл

volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ ls

xoria256.bin

volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ # но не смотря на это vim выдает ошибку при старте

volk@sivadra:~/.vim/colors$ vim

Обнаружена ошибка при обработке /home/volk/.vimrc:
строка    1:

E185: Невозможно найти цветовую схему 'xoria256'

Comment: Почему файл имеет расширение bin, а не vim? Я думал, что это была опечатка.

Comment: Он таким с сайта скачался, когда я его переименовал возникла новая ошибка.
err: please use GUI or a 256-color terminal (so that t_Co=256 could be set)

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в начало .vimrc следующие строки:

  " Configure 256 colors for xterm mode
  if &term =~ "xterm"
    let &t_Co=256
  endif

Comment: Заработало, спасибо огромное